# Azure Data Factory Copy Pipeline with Geography Data Type

Tags: azure-data-factory, upsert, sqlgeography

I am trying to get a geography data type from a production DB to another DB on a nightly occurrence. I really wanted to leverage upsert as the write activity, but it seems that geography is not supported with this method. I was reading a similar post about bringing the data through ADF as a well known text data type and then changing it, but I keep getting confused on what to do with the data once it is brought over as a well known data type. I would appreciate any advice, thank you.

Tried to utilize ADF pipelines and data flows. Tried to convert the data type once it was in the destination, but then I was not able to run the pipeline again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I tried to upsert the data with geography datatype from one Azure SQL database to another using copy activity and got error message.

[image]

- Then, I did the upsert using dataflow activity. Below are the steps.
- A source table is taken in dataflow as in below image.

```sql
CREATE  TABLE SpatialTable
( id int ,
GeogCol1 geography,
GeogCol2 AS GeogCol1.STAsText() );

INSERT  INTO SpatialTable (id,GeogCol1)
VALUES (1,geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 46.656, -122.343 46.656 )', 4326));

INSERT  INTO SpatialTable (id,GeogCol1)
VALUES (2,geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.357 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326));
```

[image]

- Then **Alter Row** transformation is taken and in Alter Row Conditions, **Upsert if** `isNull(id)==false()`is given. (Based on the column id, sink table upserted)
  [image]
- Then, in Sink dataset for target table is given. In sink settings, Update method is selected as **Allow Upsert** and required Key column is given. (Here column **id** is selected)
  [image]
- When pipeline is run for the first time, data is inserted into target table.
- When pipeline is run for the second time by updating the existing data and inserting new records to source, data is upserted correctly.

**Source** Data is changed for id=1 and new row is inserted with id=3
[image]

**Sink** data is reflecting the changes done in source.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed to have my pipeline work.